# Cant install windows. Not booting to Hard Drive

Tags: windows, boot, installation

I cannot install windows on a laptop.

- Tried several different HHDs
- Tried Windows 10 and 8.1 boot usbs
- Tried Rufus with windows 10 and 8.1 iso's
- Tried Startup Repair after installation. I get "Start-up Repair couldn't repair your PC"
- Tried bootrec /FixMbr; bootrec /fixboot; bootrec /scanos; bootrec /rebuildbcd after installation. Fixboot gives me "Access is Denied" for Windows 10 USB Key boot, but works for Windows 8.1 key. But I can do "attributes volume clear readonly" to make it work.
  Scanos identifies 0 Windows installations. I can get it identifying by making the partition with Windows "Active" with diskpart. I can then rebuildbcd.
  But still no luck.
- Tried removing battery
- Tried removing CMOS

Its a Dell XPS 15Z L511Z.
I had an SSD drive in it which I removed and used elsewhere. It was working fine with the SSD but I since wiped that. Cant get it to work with new drives.

When I first turn it on I get the Dell logo F2 for Setup F12 for Boot then it goes to black screen with a blinking underscore cursor in top left forever.
If I plug in a Windows USB boot drive I can boot from that and I can go through the windows installation process, windows then says it needs to restart. After it restarts i'm back to the black screen and have to restart installation process in an endless loop.
I can make the Hard Disk the priority but it does not change the loop.
The hard disks are recognised in the BIOS.
I did a system diagnostics test and noting came up.

Is it possible for the mobo to be broken in some way?

Update - I tried another Hard Drive and with this one instead of getting a black screen with flashing cursor it says "Operation system not found" (With the typo for Operation instead of Operating".

My issue seems to be similar to what [this](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Operation-System-Not-Found-not-a-typo/td-p/5177162) person has.

Comment: I understand you're installing on a hard disk. Try : During the installation of Windows, format the disk. Use slow format (not quick).

Comment: When you boot from the windows 10 usb drive, you can see and install to a hard drive, right? If so, then your mobo should be fine. Check your UEFI mode in BIOS. You can try changing that around, or just reset your BIOS to defaults > temporary-boot to windows USB (F12) instead of changing the boot order > erase hard drive again, format, and install windows

Comment: The bios has no UEFI mode. I already reset BIOS to defaults. I have been using the Temporary F12 boot to USB and have it left on boot to HDD as default. When installing I formated, then erased the HHD before selecting it for the new installation. Will try the slow format. These HDDs would have come from other laptops and would have had windows OS's on them in the past but I assume they are all wiped now.

Comment: "The bios has no UEFI mode." - I find that hard to believe. All OEM Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 devices were required to not only ship with the mode turned on but support it.

Comment: This guy has the same BIOS so I'll use his screenshots. No UEFI options:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/611135/operation-system-not-found-during-usb-boot

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I installed with only one Hard Drive in the laptop instead of two. No idea why.

I want as much storage as possible in the laptop so I was always trying to install with two  Hard Drives in it swapping them around with different combos from four drives.  I would delete all partitions during the install process and pick one of the disks to install Windows on leaving the other unallocated.

In the past it had two drives, but only one when I last installed windows on it so I said id try with only one and it worked.

Comment: Glad you have it working. Windows will only boot from the first partition on the *primary* drive. Many laptop BIOSs that have multiple drives don't do a good job with persistent drive designations. I have an HP Elitebook that is horrible at this. It has 2 drive bay (3 if you use the DVD bay as a drive bay) It will literally swap what it considers to be the primary and secondary drive at will. It will support Win10 on one and Linux on the other, but I often have two Linux drives in it -- and it will swap what is `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` literally over reboot.

Comment: Once you have Win10 installed, you should be able to add the second drive (and as long as it doesn't have windows on it you should be fine). If you do have windows on both, you should be able to use the laptop boot-select hot-key during boot to pick the drive to boot from. Let us know if that works as well.